# What does "n bits" in "show engine innodb status" output mean?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Like this one:

> (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
>
> RECORD LOCKS **space id 660 page no 879192 n bits 136** index
>   `uindex_nsid_path` of table `iris_v40`.`iris_name_entry` trx id
>   3269507776 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting Record lock, heap
>   no 64 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32  0:
>   len 4; hex 00092b77; asc   +w;;  1: len 30; hex
>   2fe5a4a7e8bf9e2fe696b0e5bbbae69687e4bbb6e5a4b92f4d7920446f63; asc /
>   /               /My Doc; (total 123 bytes);  2: len 4; hex 04e250fd;
>   asc   P ;;

I can understand space id and page no, but n bits is confusing me.

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfying answer to this? Also, what about space id and page no?

Comment: `space id` is something you could find in `information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES`, `page no` is something you could find in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES`.